# git match tag with multiple words

Tags: regex, git, grep

We can get the last git tag, which starts by a word(e.g TEST) as follow:

```
git describe --tag --dirty --match 'TEST*'
```

I am wondering how can I get the last tag, which starts by word1 **or** word2 (e.g. TEST **OR** RUN)?
I've tried to use regex or following but it does not work:

> git describe --tag --dirty --match 'TEST*|RUN*'

**SOLUTION:**
We can get number of commits to HEAD and compare those numbers, the one which has less commits is the more recently. You can find its script in the answer, which I have added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get number of commits to HEAD and compare those numbers, the one which has less commits is the more recently, as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
V_TEST=$(git describe --tag --dirty --match 'TEST*' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "-" }; {print $2}')
V_RUN=$(git describe --tag --dirty --match 'RUN*' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "-" }; {print $2}')
if [[ $V_TEST -gt $V_RUN ]] ; then
  VERSION=$(git describe --tag --dirty --match 'RUN*')
  echo $VERSION
else
  VERSION=$(git describe --tag --dirty --match 'TEST*')
fi
echo $VERSION
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is matched using [`fnmatch()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), which uses [shell wildcard patterns](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), not regular expressions.

As shell wildcards don't support alternation you can't do this without changing the implementation of `describe`.

Source: [git describe source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/describe.c#L153) :P

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems you are right, but what do you suggest?

Comment: @csuo: You could modify the `describe` implementation to support multiple patterns (or regular expressions)

Comment: Thanks again. I've wrote a script which finds the recent commit with mentioned tags, and it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Note: only Git 2.15 (Q4 2017) will allow multiple patterns:

> "`git describe --match`" learned to take multiple patterns in v2.13
>   series, but the feature ignored the patterns after the first one
>   and did not work at all.  This has been fixed.

See [commit da769d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da769d2986470931b8e80b8d14afcae3d7cc20d7) (16 Sep 2017) by [Max Kirillov (`max630`)](https://github.com/max630).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a515136](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a515136c523cca1d4c5ea2b3c46b3f26bbd22639), 28 Sep 2017)</sup>

```
git describe --long --tags --match="test1-*" --match="test2-*" HEAD^
```

In your case:

```
git describe --long --tags --match="TEST*" --match="RUN*"
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you could probably do something along the lines of:

`/^git describe --tag --dirty --match '(?:TEST|RUN)\*'$/`

Live demo and explanation: http://regex101.com/r/qC3gW5

Comment: I don't think he wants to match git command lines, in this case.

Comment: This does not work, as I mentioned in the question, I want to get the last tag, which starts by word1 or word2

Comment: @csuo: I think you need to clarify it for me, I don't understand what you want or what you're trying to do. If you change `(?:`into `(` the regex will capture the data.

Comment: No, I think it does not, if you see the Hasturkun's answer, he've mentioned that this match does not use regular exp.
What I am trying to do is, suppose we have two tags which one of them starts by TEST and the other one by RUN, I want to catch the one which is tagged more recently.

Comment: @csuo: then you should untag your question from regex.

Comment: @ Lindrian: Thank you for your answer. I've wrote a script which finds the recent commit with mentioned tags, and it solves the problem